# Remove index.php from URl on aws AMI Instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, url-rewriting, instance, amazon-ami

How remove **index.php** from URL on amazon aws AMI instance. Prettify url on ec2 instance for **larvel, CodeIgniter or any other framework.**

Answer (score 1):

Steps to remove index.php from url on Amazon-ec2  AMI (instance only)

1. Connect your instance using Filezila or WinSCP and open directory **/etc/httpd/conf/**  and your can see **httpd.conf** file .
2. Now check it permission by right click on **file>File permissions**.
3. IF your file permission is **other than 777** then it won't work to change permission follow further steps or jump to step 6.
4. To change file permission connect your instance using PUTTY or any other terminal but i am using PUTTY.
5. Run this command to change it's permission **sudo chmod 777  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**.
6. Now your can open **httpd.conf** file and edit.
7. Jump to **line no 151** and change **AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All**.
8. And it's done just  change it's permission to default using this command **sudo chmod 644  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf**.
   9.Don't forgot to restart services using this command **sudo service httpd restart**

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution for this problem

I had the same problem then I tried the below option and it worked!

"just change AllowOverride from None to All" in  /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf Config file

AllowOverride None  ==>  AllowOverride All

and restart apache

sudo service httpd restart

Thanks!